# Accordance between pixel and mm

Tags: c#, screen, wysiwyg, gdi, dimension

I'm doing:

```
        PhysicalParameters()
    {
        IntPtr DeskTopHWND = GetDesktopWindow();
        IntPtr HDC = GetDC(DeskTopHWND);
        int mmX = GetDeviceCaps(HDC, HORZSIZE);
        int mmY = GetDeviceCaps(HDC, VERTSIZE);
        int pxX = GetDeviceCaps(HDC, HORZRES);
        int pxY = GetDeviceCaps(HDC, VERTRES);
        ReleaseDC(DeskTopHWND, HDC);
        double CoeffPIX_MM_X = 1.0 * mmX / pxX;
        double CoeffPIX_MM_Y = 1.0 * mmY / pxY;
    }
```

The result for both is 0.25

But what I see (MS Word' WysiWyg ) it should be about 0.27

Please, explain the subject.

Comment: did you squish your monitor? or perhaps stretch it?

Comment: Isn't 0.27 about 0.25? ;) What are the limits you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Typical LCD monitors have a 96 pixel-per-inch density. This translates to a pixel size of 0.0104167 inch or 0.265 mm.

However manufacturing techniques differ drastically, and therefore pixel sizes are not fixed. Different monitors and devices will have difference pitches and densities. So the short answer is **there is no correlation between pixels and a unit of measure**. A pixel is whatever size you (or a manufacturer of a device) want it to be.

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution

Comment: How do I transfer my document from screen to Printer?
How could I be sure that the screen is printed in correct dimensions on user's PC? During printing to do the same with Printer DC? Awful.

Comment: You *can* control the dimensions things are printed on a printer, look into PostScript, PDF, and other print formats. You can never guarantee that items displayed on a monitor are a specific size due to all sorts of things beyond your control, including users' selected resolutions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Each device is going to have a slightly different HORZSIZE, HORZRES, VERTSIZE and VERTRES.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `GetDeviceCaps` for HORZSIZE doesn't actually get the horizontal size of your monitor - it gets what the size *would be* if it was a 96 DPI monitor at the current resolution.

The 96 DPI is the default, of course - users can set the system DPI and if they set it accurately, you will get the right value back for the size of the monitor.   Hardly anyone does this, though - so you will almost always get back values assuming 96 DPI.

Comment: True, but even given this fact, the ratio between size and resolution should be reliable since they're both based on 96DPI.

Comment: Yes, the *aspect ratio* is normally correct, because it assumes a pixel shape that is by far the most common, but on any monitor where you're not at exactly 96 DPI, the size to resolution ratio will be wrong.  And as he's talking about MSWord and WSIWYG, I'm assumnig he's measuring the on-screen ruler with a real one.

Comment: How do I transfer my document from screen to Printer? How could I be sure that the screen is printed in correct dimensions on user's PC? During printing to do the same with Printer DC?

Comment: You can try calling `SetProcessDPIAware`, then calling `GetDeviceCaps` with `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY` to get the DPI information, but this will only be correct if the driver is propery asking the monitor for the EDID information on DPI, which is a crapshoot.  Note that if you don't call `SetProcessDPIAware` (or set it in your manifest) you will always get a fake number (96, or whatever is set by the user).    Really, the only 100% reliable way is to ask the user to use an actual ruler to calibrate your app, and even then, most will just skip that step.

Comment: >ask the user to use an actual ruler to calibrate your app
the only way in my case