# Convert px to mm

Tags: php, math

I am creating business card maker online, now so far everything was easy until i came to card rendering. In my html document i have:

> width = 517px which is equals to 90mm
>   height = 287px which is equals to 50mm

And according to Photoshop **90mm** -> **255px** so I need to somehow convert **517px** to **255px**.

After some googling best solution i came up with so far is `(517 / 5.7) * 3` which gives me `272` and it's far from correct answer.

Any suggestions would help a lot :)

P.S I am using `php GD`.

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing up different image resolutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044476/accordance-between-pixel-and-mm

Comment: It depends entirely on your monitors pixel per inch density as to how many pixels you will get in a certain amount of space.  This means different peoples computers looking at the same website will see different values.

Comment: @BoltClock Well my image in html document is bigger so it would be easier to create what you want but when i render that image i want to shrink it to the actual size

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't CSS let you specify measurements in physical distance units? I'm sure you can use `mm` and `cm` which would translate to the correct distances when you come to print - which is surely what matters here.

Comment: @Jon Taylor I am not talking about what they see in their monitor i'm talking about image rendering and since php function `imagecreatetruecolor` accept pixels i have to use them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correlation between pixels and physical measurements depends entirely on the display and how many physical pixels there are per (square) millimeter. 72ppi ([pixels per inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density)) used to be a typical resolution, but with pixel density increasing across many devices, that's not a given anymore.

There's simply no standard formula.

Comment: okay so what if i want to create image let's say `100x100mm` with this function `imagecreatetruecolor` how can i know what numbers to use?

Comment: @Linas Is this for the purposes of printing? Who is printing the cards, you or the end user?

Comment: Yes it is for printing and i will also going to need to generate `pdf` document so it's crucial for me to understand how does this work

Comment: @Linas Then take 72ppi as a rule of thumb and create an image that has enough pixels to display as 100x100mm in size on a display with 72ppi. If that's supposed to be for printing though, you need at least 300ppi for acceptable print quality, i.e. several times the pixels.

Comment: So after many tries i got this formula `517 / 2.02` and it works perfectly with any size so far, now all that's left is to figure out how to get my text offset size etc lol, anyways you helped me a lot, so i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The resulting pixel number depends on the DPI (resolution) of the output media.

Starting with 90mm equaling ~3,54in you get:

```
72dpi:  255px
96dpi:  340px
120dpi: 425px
146dpi: 517px
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do all the calculation there is a PHP Class which can do this for you.

Here are some informatiosn what the Library can do:
When layouting things one often has to compute various positions, zoom factors, scalings and the like. When the specific sizes are of dynamical nature the layout code quicky gets a confusing endless series of mathematical equations. You name it: spaghetti code. This library tries to offer two approaches to solve this problem:

- by taking handling of units from explicit recomputation to implicit
  consideration, so all you have to do is name what unit a specific
  value is to be interpreted as
- by offering well known arithmetical concepts as types which allows to
  think in a more high level way about layouting instead of    just
  simple numeric values.

https://github.com/arkascha/php-urithmetic

Answer (score 0):

I think px divided by 2.02 works perfect in my case at any size of page. 
In **php** code i use :

```
<?php $mm = $px/2.02 ?>
```