# .draggable mm instead of px of position?

Tags: jquery-ui

can I somehow get mm instead of px of the .draggable function? When I look into my inspector when using this, I get top:'some px' left:'some px'.

Is there anyway to say from the beginning "I need mm instead of px" or convert px to mm? My parent object already has mm, so I really need mm also on the top and left values.

Comment: [from w3c](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) :  `"The so-called absolute units (cm, mm, in, pt and pc) mean the same in CSS as everywhere else. A length expressed in any of these will appear as exactly that size (within the precision of the hardware and software).` **They are not recommended for use on screen** `, because screen sizes vary so much. A big screen may be 60cm (24in), a small, portable screen is maybe only 8cm. And you don't look at them from the same distance."`

Comment: So, why exactly are you using `mm`? there is no *option* to change this, because this indeed isn't a common requirement. You'll have to calculate it using the `px` or go under the `jQuery ui` hood.

Comment: Hey. I need to export everything in mm because it generates a .xml at the end. So I really need the exact mm amount.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get it, do you want to print this or something..?

Comment: Kinda. I can't say too much about this :D ... It generates .xmls, which are converted to .pdfs. So I need the exact mm amounts

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on why you want to do this because:

> The correlation between pixels and physical measurements depends
>   entirely on the display and how many physical pixels there are per
>   (square) millimeter. 72ppi (pixels per inch) used to be a typical
>   resolution, but with pixel density increasing across many devices,
>   that's not a given anymore.
>
> There's simply no standard formula.
>   [- deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391921/1947286)

You can guesstimate it if you don't need to be that accurate by saying that a mm = 3.779528px, but for most purposes this will cause more problems than it will solve.

```js
$('.draggable').draggable({
  containment: 'parent',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    $('.pos').html(
      '<p>top:' + $('.draggable').position().top / 3.779528 + 'mm</p>' +
      '<p>left:' + $('.draggable').position().left / 3.779528 + 'mm</p>'

    );
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100mm;
  height: 100mm;
  background: silver
}
.draggable {
  height: 20mm;
  width: 20mm;
  background: grey
}
.pos {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  color blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="draggable"></div>
</div>
<div class="pos"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is I need the EXACT number of MM to export a xml after this. mm on divs work, but I need the exact mm :/

Comment: @FrederikWitte Just a thought, but could you get away with building the user interface in px and then converting everything to mm at the end? That way it may be a little off, but everything will be proportionate.

Comment: This would cause a problem. Imagine a din A4 page where you put a rectangle on the bottom. If this is just 1mm off(from height or position), you will see a white border on your page. And you only have x and y positions for these xmls.